# How to stop visual studio from scanning all files and folders in my website when degugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

While trying to debug an asp.net website in visual studio 2013 professional I am having a weird issue. The website is simple but uses flat files and folder structure and files in it for performing some operations. There are two important folder in this website that contains 100 thousands of files and images. When I try to start debugging and do not remove files from these two folder then VS crashes and restart, but if I remove files then VS proceeds normally. The files in these folders are csv, txt and image files. What I can understand is that VS goes through all these folders and files before starting the debugger, hence somehow I need to tell VS to not to consider these folders. I am not able to find anything related to it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for anybody who faces similar problem.

For some reason I dont know why, when starting degugging visual studio was scanning each and every folder, even the folders which doesnt contained any code file, this was making VS very slow due to very high number of files and out of memory exception was being thrown. Since in my case these folders doesnt contained any code file, but still were needed to run the application, I made them hidden from window explorer. This solved the problem as now vs ignores them, while still the program can output report and read reports from these hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take a look at your Event Viewer first and see if you can find anything regarding VS crash.

Also you can try running Visual Studio from the command line `devenv.exe /log` and then load your solution. If crash still happens, then go take a look at following file `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ActivityLog.xml`. Perhaps you would find some more details about the crash.

If you happen to be using ReSharper, you might want to disable it and see if that would make any difference. ReSharper likes to index source files in the background which could lead to some usability issue in VS.